# how to identify the affected product during the android in app purchase?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

the android in app billing workflow is pretty long and consists of several calls between client and server. so far i could not find a global transaction id or something like that, that would identify the initial purchase request. let's say after the request GET_PURCHASE_INFORMATION a bundle with the status FAILED is returned by the market application. how do i know which purchase is affected?

thx simon

Answer (score 0):

To link the initial request with the purchase transaction information returned by the PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED broadcast, you can use the DEVELOPER_PAYLOAD. The string you pass will be returned as is in the JSON string.

Comment: the REQUEST_ID is different for each request. for example REQUEST_PURCHASE and GET_PURCHASE_INFORMATION have different REQUEST_IDs and can not be related to each another. also the NOTIFY_ID is unique and can identify the notification process, but can not be related to the initial request.

Comment: here are the logged actions with their ids:
`-> REQUEST_PURCHASE            8419859219323261883 (req id)
<- RESPONSE_CODE               8419859219323261883 (req id)
<- IN_APP_NOTIFY              -2343381495212535024 (notify id)
-> GET_PURCHASE_INFORMATION    3418190517387724075 (req id)
<- PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED     -2343381495212535024 (notify id)
-> CONFIRM_NOTIFICATIONS       2208577407052555145 (req id)
<- RESPONSE_CODE               3418190517387724075 (req id)
<- RESPONSE_CODE               2208577407052555145 (req id)`

how can i now relate the notification id to the initial request?

Comment: I see what you mean now. To link the initial request to the transaction result (PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED), you should use the developer payload, see my revised answer.

Comment: that's still not what i'm looking for. you get the payload back on the PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED event. but you also get the product id at this point, so the payload is not necessary in my case. the question is: how can you ALWAYS identify the product? for example when you get the IN_APP_NOTIFY event. then you get neither the product id nor the payload. my current workaround is to allow just one purchase at a time. then i can store the id for the open purchase until the purchase succeeds or fails.